# ImportError: No module named statsmodels

Tags: python, import, statsmodels

I downloaded the StatsModels source from [this location](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels#downloads).

Then untarred to

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and per [this documentation](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/install.html), did this

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

It installed but when I try to import

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Astrophysics/Histogram_Fast.py", line 6, in <module>
import statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named statsmodels.api
```

I read a few post with a similar problem and checked that `setuptools` was installed and it was also in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

I'm kinda of lost on this and would appreciate any help...

I am also running

```
numpy 1.6
```

so thats not the problem.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

- you shouldn't untar it to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (you could use any temporary directory)
- you might have used by mistake a different python executable e.g., /usr/bin/python instead of the one corresponding to /usr/local/lib/python2.7

You should use `pip` corresponding to a desired python version (use `python -V` to check the version) to install it:

```
$ python -m pip install statsmodels
```

It would allow you to upgrade/uninstall it easily.

Don't install as a root to avoid the risk of messing with system python installation by accident. You could use `--user` option or virtualenv instead.

Comment: The problem was where I un tarred it

Comment: great answer. but why `pip3 install statsmodels` installs the module but then inside `python3` it cannot be imported? I only managed to solve this problem using `python 3-m pip install statsmodels `.

Comment: @makis `pip3` may use a different from `python3` executable. There may be several python3 binaries installed on a computer.

Answer (score 3):

**Install statsmodels:**

**For Window users:**

> `pip install statsmodels`

**For Mac users:**

> `pip3 install statsmodels`

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation, you can install using the following commands

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels
```

using conda

```
conda install statsmodels
```

Then restart your jupyter notebook

if you facing an error like `no module pasty`
stop your jupyter notebook and try the below command on terminal

```
pip install patsy
```

Don't forget to restart your jupyter notebook
Let's  hope

Comment: In some cases, dependencies keep the version outdated. `pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels` is the way to get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

#### Install patsy:

```
pip install --upgrade patsy
```

#### Install statsmodels

```
pip install statsmodels
```

docs [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patsy)

Comment: pip install statsmodels will automatically install/upgrade patsy.. isn't it?

Comment: In my case it didn't and the error output told me to install patsy, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade the package pytest. I had the same issue importing in a Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu python 2.7

`import statsmodels.api as sm`

I also had to restart the Jupyter notebook.

`sudo python -m pip install pytest --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing using the path directly,

For example, **pip install --user "downloaded_package_path"**

Then try importing the statsmodels, **import statsmodels.api as sm**

Answer (score 0):

Until 2022 many things changed, but if somebody have the same problem, here is what worked for me: on the left side of VS Code, there are many icons (explore, search etc). The last one is Pip manager. Click on it and search for the module to install it :)
Much better than 9 years ago haha