# How to install statsmodels for Python

Tags: python, pip, conda, statsmodels

I had to undergo a lot of problems to install sklearn and now I have the same problem for statsmodels.
I need help installing this Python module. I have all the environments ready(PIP and CONDA). What to do next? It says it is installed in the terminals but when I run the code, I get this error(BTW I am using Spyder IDE):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-5ad1e596ef83>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.formula.api as sm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

this is what I get when I type `pip show statsmodels`

```
Name: statsmodels
Version: 0.11.0
Summary: Statistical computations and models for Python
Home-page: https://www.statsmodels.org/
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD License
Location: c:\users\admin\miniconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, scipy, pandas, patsy
```

Comment: " It says it is installed in the terminals" Which one?

Comment: What is the output of `pip show statsmodels` or `python -m pip show statsmodels` if you type this in cmd?

Comment: @manojk I have edited my question to what happens when I type `pip show statsmodels` please reply soon!

Comment: From the output it seems to be installed, have to look at solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788900/importerror-no-module-named-statsmodels)

Comment: Else try to re-install, maybe not installed properly.

Comment: @manojk I have installed numpy, scipy, patsy, pandas, six, and finally statsmodels and yet my python ide give the error `No module named 'statsmodels'`

Comment: I managed to figure out the solution, I had to literally type `pip install statsmodels` in the console. But thanks a lot for your help :)